# How to geocode via For Loop using tidygeocoder

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to loop through a list of addresses and return a list of longitudes and latitudes on the original file.  I am getting an error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"` that I am confused by.  Any reason why I am getting that error?

```
library(tidygeocoder)
library(tidyverse)

id  <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
loc_address <- as.character(c("17401 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507",                            
   "16495 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507" ,                 
   "29348 Perdido Beach Blvd #3, Orange Beach, AL 36561",                
   "31000 Harbour Dr, Orange Beach, AL 36561" ,               
   "16313 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507"))

tbl <- data.frame(id, loc_address)
tbl$loc_address <- as.character(tbl$loc_address)


tbl <- tbl %>%
  mutate(long = 0,
         lat  = 0)

for(add in 1:dim(tbl) [1]) {
  print(add)
  long_lat<- geo_census(tbl$loc_address[add])
  Sys.sleep(1)
  if(dim(long_lat) [1] !=0 {
    long_lat$lat[add] = long_lat$lat
    long_lat$long[add] = long_lat$long
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to close the parentheses in the `if` statement.

Comment: Also, based on the [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidygeocoder/vignettes/tidygeocoder.html), it looks like you can geocode an entire data frame of addresses in a single function call, rather than using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on response from @eipi10, below is the working solution

```
library(tidygeocoder)
library(tidyverse)

id  <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
loc_address <- as.character(c("17401 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507",                            
   "16495 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507" ,                 
   "29348 Perdido Beach Blvd #3, Orange Beach, AL 36561",                
   "31000 Harbour Dr, Orange Beach, AL 36561" ,               
   "16313 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507"))

tbl <- data.frame(id, loc_address)
tbl$loc_address <- as.character(tbl$loc_address)


tbl <- tbl %>%
  mutate(long = 0,
         lat  = 0)

for(add in 1:dim(tbl)) [1]) {
  print(add)
  long_lat<- geo_census(tbl$loc_address[add])
  Sys.sleep(1)
  if(dim(long_lat) [1] !=0) {
    tbl$lat[add] = long_lat$lat
    tbl$long[add] = long_lat$long
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to geocode these addresses with tidygeocoder. I've set `verbose = TRUE` to output logs, but you could leave that argument out if you wanted.

```r
library(tidygeocoder)

loc_address <- c("17401 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507",                            
        "16495 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507",                 
        "29348 Perdido Beach Blvd #3, Orange Beach, AL 36561",                
        "31000 Harbour Dr, Orange Beach, AL 36561" ,               
        "16313 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507")

results <- geo_census(loc_address, verbose = TRUE)
#> Number of Unique Addresses: 5
#> Passing 5 addresses to the census batch geocoder
#> Querying API URL: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch
#> Passing the following parameters to the API:
#> format : "json"
#> benchmark : "Public_AR_Current"
#> vintage : "Current_Current"
#> 
#> Query completed in: 2.9 seconds

results
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   address                                               lat  long
#>   <chr>                                               <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 17401 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507            30.3 -87.5
#> 2 16495 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507            30.3 -87.5
#> 3 29348 Perdido Beach Blvd #3, Orange Beach, AL 36561  30.3 -87.5
#> 4 31000 Harbour Dr, Orange Beach, AL 36561             NA    NA  
#> 5 16313 Perdido Key Dr, Pensacola, FL 32507            30.3 -87.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that batch geocoding is supported as of tidygeocoder v1.0.0 (released to CRAN today) so all of these addresses are submitted in a single query (up to 10,000 addresses can be submitted in a single batch to the Census geocoder).

Also if you want to return other information outside of longitude and latitude you can use `full_results = TRUE`. See the [usage example in the tidygeocoder Readme](https://jessecambon.github.io/tidygeocoder/index.html#usage) for an example of this.